# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::error()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

apparently this works for my teacher but for me it gives the error Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::error()

Code in Question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mini-Chat</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
form
{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>

<form action="minichat-post.php" method ="post">
<p>
    <label for="username">Username</label> : <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br>
    <label for="message">Message</label> : <input type="text" name="message" id="message"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</p>
</form>
<?php
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Error :'.$e->getMessage());
}
$response = $bdd->query('SELECT username, message FROM minichat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10');
while ($data = $response->fetch())
{
echo '<p><strong>' . htmlspecialchars($data['username']) . '</strong> : ' . htmlspecialchars($data['message']) . '</p>';
}
$response->closeCursor();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

more specifically it gives me the error line 31 which is the while loop:

```
while ($data = $response->fetch())
```

going nuts here as it worked once already with a small correction but now i cant seem to find out where to make it.

EDIT: Error is now away but it wont save any messages in the database nor display them after hitting Send.
here the post php file:

```
<?php
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=minichat', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Error :'.$e->getMessage());
}

$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO minichat (username, message VALUES (?, ?)');
$req->execute(array($_POST['username'], $_POST['message']));
header('Location: ./mini-chat[conflit].php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

in here

```
fetch()
```

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Also check for post

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
   try
   {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    die('Error :'.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $response = $bdd->query('SELECT username, message FROM minichat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10');
    while ($data = $response->fetch())
    {
    echo '<p><strong>' . htmlspecialchars($data['username']) . '</strong> : ' . htmlspecialchars($data['message']) . '</p>';
    }
    $response->closeCursor();
}
?>
```

Comment: ok great that made the error go away, yet it wont save any msg or user names sent, i got 2 fields in my phpmyadmin

username & message
username is set to unique... any ideas?

Comment: sry? i added your line which made the error itself go away, but it doesnt display any chats, nor usernames i have entered. and in the database it isnt displayed either after i put some tests in

Comment: sry for spam, edited the main post to include the post php file which should send the msg and username to the database and store it there.

Comment: Nope just nothing happening. Blank page other than username message and the input fields

Comment: did it helped you in any way>> `error_reporting()`??

Comment: sorry for the late responds, no i added the error right after the If condition and before $respons->closeCursor(); 

both didnt have any effect

Comment: Add in the beginning of file within <?php ?> tags.

Comment: its not inserting also and not giving any error also??

Comment: exactly thats the thing i dont understand

Comment: did u check properly in database??

Comment: ye got username and message there username as varchar set to 32 max and message as text,

Comment: im asking if anything id getting inserted or not.

Comment: dude i got the same problem, nothing inserted, nothing saved, nothing shown even AFTER putting ur error  line....